# Lightning Connector Apex Framework step by step

Tags: apex, lightning-connect

can any one help me with a step by step (standard one) for custom apex lightning connector ?

Thank you in advance

Comment: did you check trailhead?

Comment: thank you for your answer 
there's nothing related to Custom lightning Connector in trailhead unfortunatly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you meant the Lightning **Connect** Apex Framework, you should check out the [blog entry](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/engineering/2015/05/introducing-lightning-connect-custom-adapters.html) I put on the Salesforce Engineering blog.  It demonstrates how to make a read only custom connector.

Also, I provide a sample connector that can read and write data to another Salesforce org [on my GitHub account](https://github.com/lmcalpin/custom_adapter_demo).

But the gist is, you have five methods:

- sync, which is called when an admin selects the Validate and Sync button, query
- query, which is called for SOQL, list views, detail views, etc.
- search, which is called while executing SOSL or searches
- upsertRows, which is called when inserting or updating data
- deleteRows, which is called when deleting data

and each API expects some kind of Result object to be returned.  It's up to you to map the data from however it is represented outside of Salesforce (in the web service or whatever it is you are trying to connect to) and the canonical format the Apex custom connector needs it in.

Comment: Hi Lawrence Thank you for your helpful answer, I just want to understand : what about if i have to sync more than one object by DataSource ? should i create a seperate connector for every External object even if they're using the same URL ?

Comment: The sync method returns a List of Table objects. Each Table can be mapped to a different External Object.

Comment: Hi @Lawrence really thank you about your answers what i need to know is the following : could you tell me how to add a second table ? here is the example in salesforce developer network , how can i add a second table  ?
override global List<DataSource.Table> sync() {
 List<DataSource.Table> tables = new List<DataSource.Table>();
List<DataSource.Column> columns;
columns = new List<DataSource.Column>();
    columns.add(DataSource.Column.text('ExternalId',255));
    tables.add(DataSource.Table.get('googleDrive','title',
        columns));
    return tables;
thank you in advance really

Comment: The tables.add(...) line is where we add the table to the List of tables that the connector declares it knows about. You would simply add another one of those lines, and construct the Table differently for the second table.